# "mysqli->multi_query" ⎼ throwing sql syntax error at second query

Tags: php, sql, oop

```
public function multiQueryInsert($query){
    if($this->conn->multi_query($query)){
        do{
            $this->conn->store_result();
            /*if($result = $this->conn->store_result()){
                while($row = $result->fetch_row()){
                    return $row;
                }*/
                //$result->free();
            //}
            $this->conn->more_results();
        }
        while($this->conn->next_result());
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return $this->conn->errno;
    }
    $this->conn->close();
}

$query = "INSERT INTO `table_name`(`name`, `phone`, `address`, `email`, `cell`, `pcf`, `church`, `group`, `zone`, `dob`, `occupation`, `status`) VALUES ('$names','$phone','$address','$email','$cell','$pcf','$church','$group','$zone','$dob','$occupation','$status')";
$username = explode(' ',$names);
$fname = strtolower($username[0]);
$password = $data;
$query .= "INSERT INTO `table_name2` (`uid`, `pswd`, `Name`, `Email`) VALUES ('$fname','$password','$names','$email')";

if($db->multiQueryInsert($query) === TRUE){
    echo '<div class="success">Partner added successfully</div>';
}
else{
    die('Error adding partner: '.$db->conn->error);
}
```

The first code is the method that execute the multi_query while the other codes are the query passed to the method. The error thrown is Error adding partner:

*You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near:*

```
"INSERT INTO `cec_users` (`uid`, `pswd`, `Name`, `Email`) VALUES ('kjvhm,bhjkl','')" at line 1
```

Comment: Try a ; at the end of the first query

Comment: End your queries with a `;` like you do in PHP. MySQL has to know, where one statement end and the next starts, too.

Comment: How are you managing this code? I mean whats your structure for this. Where is class declaration?

Comment: @AhmedHabib my class doesn't have anything to do with this that is why i didn't add it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `semicolon` at the end of first insert query like this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `table_name`(`name`, `phone`, `address`, `email`, `cell`, `pcf`, `church`, `group`, `zone`, `dob`, `occupation`, `status`) VALUES ('$names','$phone','$address','$email','$cell','$pcf','$church','$group','$zone','$dob','$occupation','$status');";
```